# android bluetooth routing on lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, voip

In my app through which user can call to any number, I'm starting the bluetooth through

```
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

It works on all devices, but on android 5.0.1: it uses the microphone of the phone, not the microphone of bluetooth headset.

On previous android os: it works, but not on lollipop: only incoming audio is routed to bluetooth headset, but it never uses the bluetooth microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly disabling the speakerphone? Try something like the following:

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```